# Is it possible to have an interactive step in a kubeflow pipeline?

Tags: kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I would like to have a kubeflow where, on one of the steps, one can select a value interactively based on intermediate results.

Would this be possible in kubeflow? If so, how would one go about it?

Thanks!